# Select specific element in 2D array PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query specific elements os a **array_agg** of **arrays** in PostgresSQL.

Here is the current code:

```sql
with t as (
    select 
        influence_region_id,
        ir.city_id, 
        array[c2.lat, c2.lng] as center_latlng,
        array_agg(array[c.lat, c.lng] order by "index") as path
    from influence_regions_coordinates irc 
    join coordinates c 
        on c.id = irc.coordinate_id
    join influence_regions ir 
        on ir.id = irc.influence_region_id
    join coordinates c2 
        on c2.id = ir.center 
    group by influence_region_id, ir.city_id, center_latlng
)
select * from t;
```

Which produces:

[image]

Since `center_latlng` is a simple array, I can access it using:

```sql
select influence_region_id, center_latlng[1] from t;
```

However; if i try the same with `path` which is an **array_agg** of **arrays**, I always get `NULL`

```sql
select influence_region_id, path[1] from t;
```

[image]

I've tried using `path[1.1]`, `unnest(path)` with no avail.

**How would I go about selecting any element from the `path` array?** **(and get a ARRAY[lat, lng] as a result)**

Since its an array of arrays, I would expect to do `path[1]` and get another array as a result e.g `[-30.45555,56.77888]`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `path[1:1][:]` if you don't mind getting a slice. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZCon_UnL)

```
select (array[array['a1','b1'],
              array['a2','b2']] )[1:1][:];
```

| array |
| --- |
| {{a1,b1}} |

```
select (array[array['a1','b1'],array['a2','b2']])[1][1];
```

| array |
| --- |
| a1 |

Worth a warning:

> If any dimension is written as a slice, i.e., contains a colon, then all dimensions are treated as slices.
>
> To avoid confusion with the non-slice case, it's best to use slice syntax for all dimensions, e.g., `[1:2][1:1]`, not `[2][1:1]`.

[From the doc:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)

> An array subscript expression will return null if either the array itself or any of the subscript expressions are null. Also, null is returned if a subscript is outside the array bounds (this case does not raise an error). For example, if `schedule` currently has the dimensions `[1:3][1:2]` then referencing `schedule[3][3]` yields NULL. Similarly, an array reference with the **wrong number of subscripts yields a null** rather than an error.
>
> An array slice expression likewise yields null if the array itself or any of the subscript expressions are null. However, in other cases such as selecting an array slice that is completely outside the current array bounds, a slice expression yields an empty (zero-dimensional) array instead of null. (This does not match non-slice behavior and is done for historical reasons.) If the requested slice partially overlaps the array bounds, then it is silently reduced to just the overlapping region instead of returning null.

If you're working with geometries, consider [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) to save yourself some headaches managing, indexing and processing them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that kinda works, it works for the first element, fo path[1][:] does retrieve the first ARRAY[lat,lng] from path; however, I tried path[2][:] with intentions of selecting the second array in path, instead I got the first and the second array, makes sense this being a slice, how could I select the second array inside path? thank you.

Comment: I've updated the answer: whenever you use slices, all subscripts are implicitly converted to slices, so `[2][:]` becomes `[1:2][:]`. To tighten that, you need to use `[2:2][:]` instead. It's in [the doc I linked](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING):
*If any dimension is written as a slice, i.e., contains a colon, then all dimensions are treated as slices.*

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe I've also added a note on PostGIS: if you're working with coordinates, you could store them as a proper `geometry(POINT)` type and use all sorts of tricks with them, like [index-backed search-within-distance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). Your array-of-arrays holding multiple points can be a simple `geometry(linestring)`, and you can grab its length, transscale it, intersect it, etc.

Comment: Thats what I've been playing with, this is a legacy system and I found out about PostGIS a couple days ago, so I am experimenting  with it to see how could it improve the flows we have. One thing I noticed is that I have some polygons that are not fully closed, for GMaps it doesnt seem to make a difference, it just links the last point with the first, but aparently for PostGIS, the first and last point gotta be equal in order to create a polygon. So this question is me trying to figure out how many open polygons I have in order to fix them, if you have any tips on this, its more than welcome.

Comment: Given simple enough shapes (no holes, no multi) sometimes you can get away with `st_covexhull` or `st_concavehull`, neither of which really cares what's inside and attempts to just wrap all contents in a polygon. They will smooth out the contours so your plan to instead `st_makepolygon(st_addpoint(st_makeline(point_array),point_array[1]))` is the right approach. Depending on input quality, you might also need to `st_makevalid()`